# MogoDB update taking over 1 second

Tags: mongodb

There's a very simple query:

```
db.users.update({"_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c") },{$inc: {"points" : 5}})
```

There's an index on "points" field:

```
db.users.getIndices()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "od.users",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "points" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "od.users",
        "name" : "points"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "lastActivity" : -1
        },
        "ns" : "od.users",
        "name" : "lastActivity"
    }
]
```

Some indexes are omitted for clarity.

I am running the query on MongoDB 2.2.3, on an idle database and a quick machine (Amazon EC2 Hi I/O instance) and it takes over 1.7 seconds to complete...

```
> db.system.profile.find({ns:"od.users"}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-02-13T20:44:52.858Z"),
    "op" : "update",
    "ns" : "od.users",
    "query" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c")
    },
    "updateobj" : {
        "$inc" : {
            "points" : 5
        }
    },
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nupdated" : 1,
    "keyUpdates" : 1,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(1747665)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(5964)
        }
    },
    "millis" : 1747,
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "user" : ""
}
```

Once I remove the index, query completes in no-time:

```
> db.system.profile.find({ns:"od.users"}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-02-13T20:47:03.032Z"),
    "op" : "update",
    "ns" : "od.users",
    "query" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c")
    },
    "updateobj" : {
        "$inc" : {
            "points" : 5
        }
    },
    "idhack" : true,
    "nupdated" : 1,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(153)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(5)
        }
    },
    "millis" : 0,
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "user" : ""
}
```

Collection has about 71K documents:

```
> db.users.stats()
{
    "ns" : "od.users",
    "count" : 71236,
    "size" : 2389260264,
    "avgObjSize" : 33540.06771856926,
    "storageSize" : 3987849216,
    "numExtents" : 20,
    "nindexes" : 23,
    "lastExtentSize" : 1039589376,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.0000000002382583,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 1120676144,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 3343984,
        "email" : 4578560,
        "country_1" : 2649024,
        "wPopularity" : 3278576,
        "wRandom" : 2869776,
        "wPhoto" : 2959712,
        "username_1" : 2657200,
        "tsRegistered" : 2976064,
        "likes.id" : 483610400,
        "dmForCnt_1" : 2861600,
        "wPopularity3" : 573660864,
        "tags" : 4611264,
        "status" : 3311280,
        "birthday" : 2959712,
        "gender" : 3008768,
        "points" : 2869776,
        "employee" : 2174816,
        "manualSubscription" : 2338336,
        "facebookID_1" : 3916304,
        "facebookID" : 4161584,
        "lastActivity" : 2796192,
        "isFraud" : 1537088,
        "settingsDailyMatch" : 1545264
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Is that supposed that updating indexed field takes so long? Am I missing something?

UPDATE:

I noticed that only documents larger than 100K have this issue. Other documents are updating quickly.

Comment: How much memory is used on this machine?  I know you said that this is a 71k user database (small) but is it low on memory?  If the indices do not fit in memory you could have some issues like this.  I can see by your users.stats() query that your index sizes are over 1 Gb total.

Comment: Total memory size is 60G, machine is idle:

# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         62020      61727        292          0         20      58743
-/+ buffers/cache:       2964      59055
Swap:          511          0        511

Comment: Can you run the update on a different user each time?  You may be seeing caching benefits the second time around

Comment: So the memory is full?  From what I see there (maybe i'm reading it wrong, formatting is weird) your memory looks tapped out.  It doesn't matter much if the CPU is idle when memory is full.

Comment: I noticed that it is consistently long for some documents (even if I update a document several times in a row), while it's pretty quick for the other documents. Document that takes long to update is 10x larger than the one that is quick:

Object.bsonsize(slow_object) == 532162, Object.bsonsize(fast_object) == 23183

Comment: Also I think there's plenty of memory available, it's just taken by cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slow response was because of the index on embedded documents:

```
> db.users.getIndices()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "likes.id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "od.users",
        "name" : "likes.id"
    }
]
```

Example document with likes attribute:

```
> obj = db.users.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c")})
> Object.bsonsize(obj)
532162
> obj.likes.length
4770
> obj.likes[0]
{
    "id" : "103128829727364",
    "name" : "Jennifer Lopez",
    "category" : "Musician/band",
    "hidden" : false,
}
```

So there is 4770 embedded likes documents, and these are indexed on likes.id attribute.

When I run an update on this document, even though it doesn't touch the likes:

```
> db.users.update({"_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c") },{$addToSet: {"otherPhotos" : "holipiuouiouioiuoi1"}})
```

it takes long:

```
> db.system.profile.find({op:"update"}).sort({ts:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-02-20T08:59:30.707Z"),
    "op" : "update",
    "ns" : "od.users",
    "query" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c")
    },
    "updateobj" : {
        "$addToSet" : {
            "otherPhotos" : "holipiuouiouioiuoi1"
        }
    },
    "idhack" : true,
    "nupdated" : 1,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(1752759)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(83)
        }
    },
    "millis" : 1752,
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "user" : ""
}
```

but when I remove the index it works blazing fast:

```
> db.users.dropIndex("likes.id")
{ "nIndexesWas" : 2, "ok" : 1 }
> db.users.update({"_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c") },{$addToSet: {"otherPhotos" : "holipiuouiouioiuoi12hkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkj"}})
> db.system.profile.find({op:"update"}).sort({ts:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-02-20T09:02:13.747Z"),
    "op" : "update",
    "ns" : "od.users",
    "query" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c")
    },
    "updateobj" : {
        "$addToSet" : {
            "otherPhotos" : "holipiuouiouioiuoi12hkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkj"
        }
    },
    "idhack" : true,
    "nupdated" : 1,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(1137)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(5)
        }
    },
    "millis" : 1,
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "user" : ""
}
```

Once offending index has been removed, I was able to add index on "points" and original query response time is now only 1 ms:

```
> db.users.ensureIndex({points:1})
> db.users.getIndices()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "od.users",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "points" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "od.users",
        "name" : "points_1"
    }
]
> db.users.update({"_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c") },{$inc: {"points" : 5}})
> db.system.profile.find({op:"update"}).sort({ts:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-02-20T09:12:37.664Z"),
    "op" : "update",
    "ns" : "od.users",
    "query" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50710913a6427bfa2600000c")
    },
    "updateobj" : {
        "$inc" : {
            "points" : 5
        }
    },
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nupdated" : 1,
    "keyUpdates" : 1,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(1225)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(4)
        }
    },
    "millis" : 1,
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "user" : ""
}
>
```

So it seems that adding index on an array of embedded documents in Mongo can degrade update performance significantly if this array size can be quite large.